# Get route value from inside a decorator

Tags: python, flask, decorator, python-decorators

In Flask, how do you get a route value (eg. '/admin') inside a decorator? I need to pass certain string to the DB depending on which route was used (and they all use the same decorator).

```
@app.route('/admin')
@decorator
def admin(data):
     do_something(data)
```

I couldn't find information about how to do it in Python. Is it possible?

Comment: Why not rewrite your decorator to accept the url as an argument and automatically apply the `app.route` decorator? Then you could just write `@decorator('/admin')`.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a new decorator which get the current route path then do something with it:

```
from functools import wraps
from flask import request

def do_st_with_path(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        path = request.path
        do_anything_with_path(path)
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated_function
```

And for every route, add this decorator as the second one:

```
@app.route('/admin')
@decorator
def admin(data):
     do_something(data)
```

---

Another solution without adding a new decorator: use `before_request`. Before each request, you can also check the route path:

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    path = request.path
    do_anything_with_path(path)
```