# how to pass param value parsed from a route url to another decorator

Tags: python, flask, flask-restplus

I would like to pass a param parsed from route url to another decorator

I understand we could re-implement decorator as shown in this example [Get route value from inside a decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48458780/get-route-value-from-inside-a-decorator)

I feel this is bit of hack. Is there any other alternative?

```py
@api.route('/areas/<area_id>')
@api.param('area_id', 'area id')
class Area(Resource):
    """
        Area Info
    """
    @api.doc('a business area info')
    @api.marshal_list_with(_area, envelope='area') <<<
    def get(self, area_id):
        return get_area_info(area_id)
```

In the above example, I would like to pass `<area_id>` as envelope value instead of 'area' as

```
@api.marshal_list_with(_area, envelope=<area_id>)
```

than

```
@api.marshal_list_with(_area, envelope='area')
```